# t4 "using" keyword

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, t4

I'm new with t4.

I would like to generate code to cs file.
I created a new tt file.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

class IOperation {

<#
OperationSection section = null;

#>
}
```

OperationSection is a class in the same assembly.
I assume that I should use the "using" keyword.

How I do it?
Now I receiving an error

Error   2   Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'OperationSection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586948.aspx) directive:

```
<#@ import namespace="YourNamespace" #>
```

Additionally, you might need to add an [`assembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946) directive to reference the assembly the class is defined in:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\MyProject\bin\Debug\SomeLibrary.Dll" #>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [`import`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586948.aspx) directive for the namespace `OperationSection` is in. They look like this:

```
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
```